# R rugarch package Error in .doLoadActions

Tags: r, rstudio

when I load `rugarch` package I receive the following `error message`:

```
library(rugarch)
Error in .doLoadActions(where, attach) : 
  error in load action .__A__.1 for package multicool: loadModule(module = "Multicool", what = TRUE, env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "Multicool": evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rugarch’
```

It **can** be solved by **reinstalling R and R studio,** but it has happened to me for the second time.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Installing Rstudio  is definitely unrelated; and re-installing R is not needed, but re-installing  rugarch and multicool ...may have been the reason.   I also see the identical problem as you, but only in 'R CMD check' when building a **vignette** which uses the rugarch package.... and interestingly I only see it when using *new* versions of R (>= 3.3.0) but not when using R 3.2.1 (in 'R CMD check ...')  .... pretty confusing indeed, and I am also grateful for help / suggestions

Comment: Reinstalling those 2 packages does not help. If I only reinstalled packages OR r studio, nothing happened. Only doing everything helped... I had to do it 3 times already :(

Comment: Actually it is more important to reinstall the  `Rcpp` pacakge and `multicool`.  This solved the problem for me.  I reiterate re-installing Rstudio is absolute nonsense. What you probably did is re-installing rstudio (no effect), re-installing R (and hence deleting all packages installed after that including Rcpp and multicool !!)... but what really helped was **only** the re-installation of the two packages; all the other steps were entirely unnecessary.